# strlen return wrong answer in c

Tags: arrays, c, strlen

I am writing a program which convert decimal number to roman number. I use 4 arrays `thousands`, `hundreds`, `tens`, `units` to store digits in roman number, then copy each digit to `res` array, I use `str` pointer to track where the string in `res` begin. When I test with input `128`, it prints out `CXXVIIIIX` which must be `CXXVIII`. I have tried to debug and got the result when `tmp=8` is `strlen(units[tmp-1]) = 6`, which means `strlen` also counts `IX`. And for some case like `3888`, the program prints out trash value.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    int n=128;

    char thousands[][4]={"M","MM","MMM"};
    char hundreds[][5]={"C","CC","CCC","CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
    char tens[][5]={"X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
    char units[][5]={"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};

    char res[16];
    res[15]='\0';    //add nul to the last character of res array
    char *str=res+14;   //str tracks where the string start
    int tmp;
    
    
    //store roman digits in res array in reverse order, 
    //start from units->tens->hundreds->thousands
    if (n!=0)
    {
        tmp=n%10;
        if (tmp!=0)
        {
            str-=strlen(units[tmp-1]);  //str steps back several address to store new digits
            strncpy(str, units[tmp-1], strlen(units[tmp-1]));   //use strncpy to copy without '\0'
            
        }
        n/=10;
    }
    
    if (n!=0)
    {
        tmp=n%10;
        if (tmp!=0)
        {
            str-=strlen(tens[tmp-1]);
            strncpy(str, tens[tmp-1], strlen(tens[tmp-1]));
            
        }
        n/=10;
    }
    
    if (n!=0)
    {
        tmp=n%10;
        if (tmp!=0)
        {
            str-=strlen(hundreds[tmp-1]);
            strncpy(str, hundreds[tmp-1], strlen(hundreds[tmp-1]));
            
        }
        n/=10;
    }
    
    if (n!=0)
    {
        tmp=n%10;
        if (tmp!=0)
        {
            str-=strlen(thousands[tmp-1]);
            strncpy(str, thousands[tmp-1], strlen(thousands[tmp-1]));
            
        }
        n/=10;
    }
    
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

So why does this happen and how to fix it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The string `"LXXX"` needs *five* characters to include the null-terminator! You have the same problem in the other arrays as well.

Comment: There's also a case where [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) will not add the null-terminator. If you don't have a null-terminator in your string, it can't be used by the standard C string functions as they will go out of bounds and give you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have change the boundary of `units`, `tens`, `hundreds` to `5`, `thousands` to `4` and it solve for `n=128`, but when `n=3888` it still prints out trash value. How do I solve it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I use `strncpy` to not copy the '\0' to `res`, and I also add '\0' at `res[15]` at the beginning. So is it good enough?

Comment: `strncpy` is a dangerous function that shouldn't be used for any purpose. See [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)

Comment: @Becker Please [edit] your question and copy&paste your modified code instead of describing what you changed. You have to add `'\0'` immediately after the last valid character. If your string has less than 15 characters, `res[15]='\0'`; is not correct. You could use `res[15]={0};` to fill all elements of `res`.

Comment: correction: `char res[16] = {0};` would initialize the whole array with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing the array size for all string literals, there is an off-by-one error and an uninitialized char array element.

- `char res[16];` would be enough for `"MMMDCCCLXXXVIII"` with a trailing `'\0'`.
- With `res[15]='\0';` you store the string termination in the last element.
- `char *str=res+14;` sets the pointer to the uninitialized character before this.
- `str-=strlen(something)` moves the pointer according to the length of the string to insert. The following `strncpy` will not overwrite the uninitialized character.

The result will always contain an uninitialized trailing character which may or may not be visible.

A result of the maximum length (`"MMMDCCCLXXXVIII"`) will begin one character before the first array element because of the trailing uninitialized character. You would have a result string `"MMMDCCCLXXXVIII*"` where **`*`** is uninitialized. The second `M` is the first array element of `res`, the first `M` would be one before the first element.

**Example to demonstrate the off-by-one error:**

Based on the original (wrong) code from the question.

Note that this is not the full code but a reduced extract intended to show how the variable values change with input value `n=3888`. (To make the code shorter, the `if (tmp!=0)` guards from the original code are missing here.)

In the comments that show variable values, `*` is used to indicate an uninitialized character.

```
int n=3888;

char res[16];
// * indicates an uninitialized character
res[15]='\0';  // "***************\0"

// The following initialization is wrong.
char *str=res+14; // str = &res[14] (the last uninitialized character)
int tmp;

// The following block leaves the last character of res uninitialized.
tmp=n%10; // tmp = 8
str-=strlen(units[tmp-1]); // "VIII" (strlen = 4) -> str = &res[10]
strncpy(str, units[tmp-1], strlen(units[tmp-1])); // "**********VIII*\0"
n/=10; // n = 388

// Here, str points to the first character written by the previous block.
tmp=n%10; // tmp = 8
str-=strlen(tens[tmp-1]); // "LXXX" (strlen = 4) -> str = &res[6]
strncpy(str, tens[tmp-1], strlen(tens[tmp-1])); // ******LXXXVIII*\0"
n/=10; // n = 38

/* ...*/

// final result would be

// str = &res[-1]
// str -> "MMMDCCCLXXXVIII*\0"
// res =   "MMDCCCLXXXVIII*\0"

// The last strncpy tries to write a character 'M' one 
// element before the beginning of the array res
// corresponding to strncpy(res[-1], "MMM", 3)
```

As a fix I propose

```
char res[16] = {0}; // initialize the whole array with 0
char *str=res+(sizeof(res)-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... and how to fix it?

- Consider writing units in 1,000s, then 100s, tens, ones order.
- Add a "zero" to each unit list.
- Roll into a helper function.
- Change types from character arrays to arrays of pointers.

Example

```
void print_roman(int n) {
  static const char *thousands[] = {"", "M", "MM", "MMM"};
  static const char *hundreds[] = {"", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
  static const char *tens[] = {"", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
  static const char *ones[] = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};
  static const char **units[] = {thousands, hundreds, tens, ones};
  int units_n = sizeof units / sizeof units[0];

  assert(n > 0 && n < 4000);
  char res[16];
  char *p = res;
  int multiplier = 1000;
  for (int i = 0; i < units_n; i++) {
    strcpy(p, units[i][n / multiplier]);
    p += strlen(p);
    n %= multiplier;
    multiplier /= 10;
  }
  printf("<%s>\n", res);
}

int main() {
  print_roman(3888);
  print_roman(3999);
  print_roman(1010);
  print_roman(42);
}
```

Output

```
<MMMDCCCLXXXVIII>
<MMMCMXCIX>
<MX>
<XLII>
```